# What and where is this Yhwach’s quote mentioned?

Tags: bleach

I’m sure that I came across Yhwach saying something like this:

> In my eyes, there’s no distinction between having a plan and...

What is the full quote? And what chapter is this on?

Comment: @W.Are Manga, of course. Yhwach only appears in manga.

Comment: Re-read bleach recently, don't remember this quote though. It's possible that the translation varies between scanlators and this one is not mainstream